# Spring Boot beans overriding

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to override some beans in my integration test. 
But I do not want some beans from production configuration were initialized before.

**Note: Not only override them and use in tests but stop initialization.**

I know that is possible to override beans but they still initialize before running integration test.

Is there any config property for that?

Thanks!

PS. I use Spring Boot 2.5.x

Comment: Use a different profile for your tests and define appropriate beans for the test profile.

Comment: Thanks! Can I hack something instead of rewriting configs?

Comment: you can  provide a different bean in your tests